# Texmaker bibtex works with \input not with \include

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, input, include

I use `bibtex` 0.99d with `Texmaker` 4.3. I have a multi .tex file document with the main document using `\include{}` for chapters. The bibtex configured as `bibtex build/%.aux` doesn't work. However when compiling the .aux files from terminal in the build folder it works fine. It work to if I use `\input{}` instead of `\include{}`.  How do I configure Texmaker/bibtex to work with `\include{}` command?

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: build/rozprawa.aux I couldn't open auxiliary file wprowadzenie.aux ---line 11 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{wprowadzenie.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file obiekt_badan.aux ---line 12 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{obiekt_badan.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file procesy_laczeniowe.aux ---line 13 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{procesy_laczeniowe.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file procesy_elektrodowe.aux ---line 14 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{procesy_elektrodowe.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file materialy_stykowe.aux ---line 15 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{materialy_stykowe.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file rezystancja_zestykowa.aux ---line 16 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{rezystancja_zestykowa.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file teza_cel.aux ---line 17 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{teza_cel.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file uklad_pomiarowy.aux ---line 18 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{uklad_pomiarowy.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file wyniki_badan.aux ---line 19 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{wyniki_badan.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file wnioski.aux ---line 20 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{wnioski.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file bibliografia.aux ---line 21 of file build/rozprawa.aux : \@input{bibliografia.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no \citation commands---while reading file build/rozprawa.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file build/rozprawa.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file build/rozprawa.aux (There were 14 error messages)
>   Process exited with error(s)

Comment: `bibtex build/%.aux ` looks wrong should't it be `bibtex build/%` as you should always pass the tex  filename with no extension to bibtex

Comment: Sounds as if you are storing the auxiliary files in another folder. This is a constant source for problems as tools don't find the files where there expect them. You probably will have to switch to the build folder and call bibtex there (and then hope that pdflatex finds the bbl).

Comment: Turned off the build folder and everything works fine. Not ideal solution as I would like more organized workplace.